# Python 3 Assume Module Namsepace

Tags: python, import, module, namespaces

quick question regarding python namespaces. I am new to python, so this may be a novice question and have a simple answer, but I have searched and can't seem to find it.

My question is simply to know if there is a way to state a namespace so that you do not need to say the module name each time you access a class declared inside it.
For example:

```
>>> import fractions
>>> myFrac = fractions.Fraction("3/4")
>>> str(myFrac)
'3/4'
>>> myFrac = Fraction("3/4")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Fraction' is not defined
>>>
```

I would like to know if there is a way to avoid the need of typing the module name. I am also interested in whether or not doing so is the conventional to write code in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `from <module> import <class>` to shorten your work

```
from fractions import Fraction
```

Edit:
Since this question is about namespaces, you're also allowed to do give fancier names

```
from animals import Dog as Scooby
```

and thereafter use the module name Scooby. Though this make it hard to track module usages later on.

Comment: Wow, painfully simple. I had seen that, but as of yet not understood what it was doing. Thank you, and cheers.

Comment: Added a bit more detail. Cheers!